# Vue Resource $http not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I have this code in my **ready** method:

`this.$http.get('url',{},{
      headers: {
            "X-App-Token": "token"
         }
      }).then(  (data) => this.$set('cdata',data.data))
        .catch( (error) => console.log('Got a problem'+error));`

and its working well, the probelm is when i move this to a another functtion  in methods object it doesn't work.

```
ready(){
this.getJsonData();
},

methods: {
getJsonData: () => {
this.$http.get('url',{},{
  headers: {
        "X-App-Token": "token"
     }
  }).then(  (data) => this.$set('cdata',data.data))
    .catch( (error) => console.log('Got a problem'+error));
},
},
```

The error:

```
src\src\App.vue:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$http' of undefined

//this becomes undefined.
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to solve this you are missing `vue.use()`

To solve this you need to add

```
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VueResource);
```

To your main.ts and it should be all fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be the use of the arrow to generate the function. May be causing that function to be in an undefined scope?  Try this:

```
methods: {
  getJsonData(){
    this.$http.get('url',{},{
      //...
```